# Single API for 2D and 3D graphics operations in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphic

Does the OpenGL have a common API(s) that can be used to perform 2D and 3D graphics operations? In other words, instead of using separate APIs for 2D and 3D, is there any common API that can used to perform both?

Comment: `OpenGL` itself doesn't have anything for "2D". If what you are talking about is something like `glVertex2f`, then it's simply equivalent to `glVertex3f` with `z=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't separate APIs for 2D and 3D rendering in OpenGL. Everything is 3D. So yes, there is a common API, which is OpenGL itself.

To render a 2D scene with OpenGL, set up an orthographic projection matrix, disable depth testing, and then pass 0 in for the Z value of each vertex.